# Should I try to minimize .htaccess redirects? (+ bonus questions)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

In my .htaccess file, I'm redirecting in 3 cases:

1. HTTP to HTTPS
2. Trimming trailing slash if the path is not a directory
3. If there is www. before the domain

Now, the question is: how expensive is .htaccess redirection? For example, if I'm cutting out www., should I also try to trim trailing slash in the same rule? It's going to make my .htaccess a little more complicated, but is it worth it?

If yes, what is the optimal .htaccess to do those things? My current .htaccess is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Remove www...
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

    # Redirect To HTTPS...
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And now promised bonus questions:

1. Why are online tutorials always giving `^(.*)$` as an example of "entire path" pattern, even though they don't use it in the rule? Isn't simple `.` enough and faster?
2. Are Rewrite Conditions always regex? I've seen both:

`RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$`

And:

`RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80`

Isn't this second RewriteCond wrong? Won't it also catch 180, 8080 ports etc.?

Comment: "how expensive is .htaccess redirection" --- at least 1 RTT

Comment: @zerkms Is this something to be worried about? What I meant with this question, is what exactly is going to be performed. Is there going to be entire domain lookup once again?

Comment: "Is there going to be entire domain lookup once again?" --- you cannot say that. Most likely no, but there is no standard that *guarantees* you it. Btw, I personally follow the simple rule when I bother about performance optimisations: I don't care about anything I cannot reliably measure. So, answer yourself, which of the concerns addressed in the question you can measure reliably?

Comment: @zerkms Hmm, interesting strategy, but I personally don't agree with it. If I don't know if something is going to cause trouble or not, but I assume it might do so, I protect against it.

Comment: @RoboRobok 1. performance optimisation *is* a rocket science. 2. no one can predict what would not work for you specifically 3. there are no universal recipes that work for everyone 4. unless you're google-fb-amazon-size - almost everything would work for you equally good. 5. When you grow large enough and have any "serious" load - you would be confident enough to make a research and not ask vague questions on SO

Comment: @zerkms Yeah, except none of those 5 statements match my question.

Comment: [Please avoid "bonus questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts).

Comment: 1. I have answered your primary question 2. Both bonus questions can be answered with the help of apache documentation `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @zerkms 99% of questions can be answered with other online resources.

Comment: And grass is green. (do we just make obvious statements here?)

Comment: This question really does not deserve a downvote,

Answer (score 1):

> how expensive is .htaccess redirection?

It is negligible for the server. For the client it's 1 RTT (possibly followed by more, for instance in case of HTTP -> HTTPS)

> For example, if I'm cutting out www., should I also try to trim trailing slash in the same rule?

It's up to you. If you can and you think it keeps it still maintainable and you still think it's worth saving 1 RTT - go for it. Otherwise - don't.

> It's going to make my .htaccess a little more complicated, but is it worth it?

There is no absolute measurement for that. Does it worth it **for you**?

> Why are online tutorials always giving ^(.*)$ as an example of "entire path" pattern, even though they don't use it in the rule? Isn't simple . enough and faster?

Technically `^(.*)$` matches an empty string, `.` does not. So in case if you don't capture the result - `.?` would behave similarly.

> Are Rewrite Conditions always regex?

Nope. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

> Isn't this second RewriteCond wrong? Won't it also catch 180, 8080 ports etc.?

If you listen to more ports than just `80` - then it may cause false positives, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want your users to always connect via HTTPS, I'd suggest adding a [Strict-Transport-Security](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_Cheat_Sheet) header. It tells the browser to remember to never connect over an insecure line:

```
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS
```

This tells the browser to transparently upgrade requests to TLS for the next year.